# ProxyPass doesn't pass as expected

Tags: apache

Our Apache on the server `myserver` allows users to access the app `myapp` using the URL https://myserver/myapp.

The corresponding Apache configuration looks like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ProxyPass /myapp http://localhost:8077/myapp
  ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://localhost:8077/myapp
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Now though, we have to reconfigure `myapp` and remove the context from http://localhost:8077/**myapp**.
We changed the Apache configuration to:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ProxyPass /myapp http://localhost:8077
  ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://localhost:8077
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately this configuration **doesn't work**!
Any idea how this problem can be fixed?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, with "doesn't work". What's the behaviour? Is there an error message? What's in the log files?

Comment: The error message is "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: I have an impresson that 'myapp' used in ProxyPass must also appear in the http address in the same command.